# Is my Indian passport damaged?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, damaged-passports

I'm up for a passport expiry and renewal but in my recent travels I had some trouble with the passport in the Indian airport while trying to board a flight to US. The booklet seems to be coming off from the passport cover and it is progressively getting worse, in a few more rough uses, the booklet would come off and it's pretty visible too (see images below).

I'm not sure if I should apply for a new passport here in the US due to "expiry" or due to "damaged". I'm also on a tight visa renewal schedule so the faster I get it done, the better. Also looks like I cannot apply under tatkaal for damaged passports. Do you guys suggest I try my luck and apply tatkaal renewal due to "expiry" or should I bite the bullet and do apply regular renewal due to "damaged"?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!!

Here are two pictures of the passport showing damage [image], [image].

Comment: You may want to check some passport protection covers (and test with the old passport). It the problem is just the cover pages (and they contains only generic text, so not valid on all countries), it may be okayish (depending on officers). Else it is definitely considered damages (integrity of binding/pages, the officers should be confident that pages were not swapped with other passports).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This is definitely considered damaged. My wife's passport had some brown spots and they (passport office) said it was damaged.

You have to renew it anyway. You can try your luck and say that its nearing expiry. They might ask you to pay extra for damaged on the spot (at passport office) the worst case.

Comment: Thanks Anish, looks like VFS is the entity getting renewal applications instead of the consulate itself, so the only option I have is to mail the passport to them and get it back :-(

Also, since the passport is damaged, when I get a new passport, will the consulate take the damaged passport or void it by punching holes or something?

Comment: For Indian passport, it will be voided by a seal and a hole in ID page and will be given back to you.